# Inserting index that already exist into the tree

Tags: algorithm

I'm wondering if it is possible to insert indexed node into the tree that has index number that is already inside this tree without making it cost too much. For example if I've got tree nodes with index numbers from 1 to 10 and I want to insert node that is supposed to have index number 8. So is it a way to for example reorganize this tree somehow or do I have to increment values 9 and 10? And if there is other way than incrementing how should I place indexes inside this tree?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by `tree`. There are a lot of `tree` data structures.

Comment: I mean tree in general that has indexed nodes

Comment: Is there a rule for indexing the nodes ?

Comment: I have no specific rule it just needs to have functionality mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own structure you can just insert it like any other node.  It should just work unless you do something special when you see equal keys during the insert.

Depending on the condition you set for comparison it will end up to the left or right of equal valued nodes (might be altered if your tree balances itself somehow). Obviously they will not be the left/right child, but will be inserted somewhere in that subtree. Your condition should be something like (`if <= go left else go right`, you can't have `if < go left ; if > go right` because now you have a third case for equality).

Don't expect look-ups to work (you need to handle a range of values, not just a single node).

If you use C++ `map` or `set` see `multimap` or `multiset`

Comment: I know that it will end to the left or right but how can I place a node in a tree which is full of nodes without moving other nodes left or right. I can't imagine how should this work. Should I store more than two children in each node?

Comment: Let's say you want to put in on the left. You go to the left node (same code you used so far). You compare what you want to insert with whatever node is there. Because it's a search tree it will now fail the comparison and tell you to go right. You keep going down until you reach a point where there's no right child. When you get there you create a new node for the value you want to insert and link it as the right child of the node where you stopped.

Comment: The nodes with the same value might not be close neighbours (depending on the tree), but if you do an in-order traversal you should get the same value nodes one after the other.